# JavaFx - values from TableColumn do not change

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to get the value of the editable table using javaFX Scene builder, but I can not get the updated value.

I' have table with 2 columns: name column and value column.
whenever the user change on of the value of value column, I want to react.

But when I print the new change value, it always displays the default value.

```
public class MesssageField
{

    private final StringProperty fieldName;
    private final StringProperty fieldValue;

    public MesssageField(String fieldName, String fieldValue) {
        this.fieldName = new SimpleStringProperty(fieldName);
        this.fieldValue = new SimpleStringProperty(fieldValue);        
    }


    public StringProperty getFieldNameProperty() {
        return fieldName;
    }

    public StringProperty getFieldValueProperty() {
        return fieldValue;
    }

    public void setFieldValue(String fieldValue) {
        this.fieldValue.set(fieldValue);
    }

    public String getFieldName() {
        return fieldName.get();
    }


    public String getFieldValue() {
        return fieldValue.get();
    }

}
```

The controller class has:

```
private static ObservableList<MesssageField> obserListMsgsField;

@FXML
private TableView<MesssageField> msgTableView;

@FXML
private TableColumn<MesssageField, String> fieldNameColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<MesssageField, String> fieldValueColumn;

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1)
{
    // create List Of fields
    obserListMsgsField = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    fieldValueColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

    // Initialize the person table with the two columns.
    fieldNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getFieldNameProperty());
    fieldValueColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getFieldValueProperty());  
}
```

the onEditFieldValueCommit method attached to "on edit commit"

```
@FXML
public void onEditFieldValueCommit() {

    MesssageField messageField = msgTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    // get field name
    String fieldName = messageField.getFieldName();

    // get field value       
    String valueString = messageField.getFieldValue(); 

    // debug print
    System.out.print("\n[DEBUG] Field Name = " + fieldName + " = " + valueString);  
}
```

But the output is always the default value and not the changed value.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you using `onEditFieldValueCommit()`? Your accessor naming is wrong: `getFieldNameProperty()` should be `fieldNameProperty()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onEditFieldValueCommit` method you are not using the parameter required, and then you are not updating the list `obserListMsgsField`.

First, you need to add a parameter of the type `TableColum.CellEditEvent`, which is the event that is fired when a user performs an edit on the table cell.

Then you just get the new value or the row affected, updating the list:

```
@FXML
public void onEditFieldValueCommit(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<MesssageField, String> t) {
    t.getRowValue().setFieldValue(t.getNewValue());

    System.out.print("\n[DEBUG] Field Name = " + t.getRowValue().getFieldName() + 
            " = " + t.getRowValue().getFieldValue());
}
```

Comment: As Uluk points out in the comments above, if you follow the correct naming pattern for the properties, the `onEditCommit` handler is unnecessary.